# "Battery is not charging"?

Tags: hardware, battery

When I connect the charger cable to my Macbook pro, sometimes the battery is not charged and I can read near the clock: "Battery is not charging".

If I unplug and reconnect the cable, it usually starts to charge again.

Even if the battery is not charging, the mac is not in "battery mode" (the charger works): it is just a battery issue.

thanks

Comment: When "battery is not charging", what's the percentage charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually not a bug, but a feature: as the battery ages by charge cycles, your computer won't charge if it's almost full in order to extend the battery's life. By unplugging and replugging the power supply, you force a battery recharge until it's full.

Comment: Could you point me to where this feature is documented?